# Get Css value of an object with two color property

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the CSS value of my object but evey time I use `getCSSValue("color")`, the return is always `#52483D`. How can I make it return `#8D847C` instead?

this is the screenshot of my objects css property

[image]

Comment: To be more clear, it seems the problem is the `getCssValue()` method used by selenium returns the natural color instead of the psuedo-class color override when the anchor has been "visited"

Comment: Can you post the code you've been using?

Comment: You can't do it via a webdriver. Read sjelin's answer in https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2675

Comment: @ArunKumar oh man, that's bad news. :(

Comment: @Okomikeruko basically this is what I'm doing. localDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='related_inner_container']//a[text()='Coupons & Deals']")).getCssValue("color");

Comment: I found this page: https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-get-css-values-using-webdriver and it seemed to be using `getCssValue("color")` in a testing capacity before and after a hover-state is also coded.

Comment: @Okomikeruko thanks! I saw it, but it is more on hover on objects and then get the css value. My scenario is a bit different.